# Как сделать, чтобы шарик оставался в блоке и не вылазил за границы

Tags: jquery

Нужно, чтобы шарик оставался в блоке и не вылазил за границы. Как максимально лаконично это сделать в коде? Именно используя jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mobileCircle = $('#mobileCircle');
    $('#wrapper').mousemove(function(e){
          mobileCircle.css({'top': e.pageY,'left': e.pageX});
   });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    height: 480px;
    width: 640px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: auto;
}

#mobileCircle {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="top">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="mobileCircle">
            </div>
        </div>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>    
    </body>
```

Comment: очевидно, перед вызовом `.css` нужно просто проверить, что шарик с новыми координатами не вылезает за границы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так попробуйте
Идея следить за границами и следить чтоб элемент не двигался дальше границ

50 - диаметр круга

2 - толщина границы

480 - высота

640 - ширина

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mobileCircle = $('#mobileCircle');
    $('#wrapper').mousemove(function(e){
      let top = Math.min(480 + this.offsetTop - 50 + 2, e.pageY);
      let left = Math.min(640 + this.offsetLeft - 50 + 2, e.pageX);

      top = Math.max(this.offsetTop + 2, top);
      left = Math.max(this.offsetLeft + 2, left);
      
      mobileCircle.css({'top': top,'left': left});
   });
   
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    height: 480px;
    width: 640px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: auto;
}

#mobileCircle {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 0px; // изменил окружность для наглядности
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="top">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="mobileCircle">
            </div>
        </div>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>    
    </body>
```

**Upd.**

> Fortunately, jQuery normalizes the .pageX and .pageY properties so
> that they can be used in all browsers. These properties provide the X
> and Y coordinates of the mouse pointer relative to the top-left corner
> of the document.

Так что нужно пересчитать относительно документа.

Comment: слева не доходит до границы, а справа заходит на половину круга

Comment: @Grundy я так понимаю минус от вас. Подправлю завтра ответ чтоб доходило. Мне с телефона не совсем удобно считать. Нужно ещё подсчитать отступы и толщину линий и прочее. Но идея все также. Не выходить за рамки. Нужно подобрать цифры правильно. Решается про100 подбором.

Comment: И к стати у меня с лева и с права все нормально. Беда с верхом и низом

Comment: Думаю может из-за того что с телефона.

Comment: https://priscree.ru/img/aea257e9b8f0cf.jpg - это не нормально

Comment: @Grundy спорить не стану. Ответ предельно прост. Нужно изменять left и top. Ограничивать по размерам. Каковы величины это нужно считать. Я указал как это делается. Вот следить за падингами и шириной рамок я не стал. Нужно всего лишь подсчитать. Я сказал что с телефона набираю.

Comment: ну сейчас в ответе указано только _следить за границами и следить чтоб центр попадал в границы - 25_ - из этого вообще непонятно, что нужно делать, в то же время в примере поведение не корректное

Comment: @Grundy в примере как раз таки понятно. Нужно просто пересчитать координаты относительно начала документа. Завтра подправлю.

Comment: @Grundy как и обещял пересчитал величины дополнил ответ

Comment: @Grundy надеюсь "квадратик" не выходит на вашем браузере